# How to play an array of audioclips to be repeated at a set delay?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

This is the segment of the code in where the audio clip is played when space is held, right now it delays the initial sound but I want to be able to delay the sounds when they are repeated.

I am aware of `audio.PlayDelayed` but Could not figure out how to get it to work.

```
void AudioEnable()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Invoke("Audio", audioDelay);

    }      
} 

void Audio()
{
    AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>(); // play fire sounds from array when space is pressed
    audio.PlayOneShot(fireSounds[Random.Range(0, fireSounds.Length)]);        
}
```

I will continue looking for a solution but in the meantime help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"but I want to be able to delay the sounds when they are repeated"* What do you mean by when they are repeated?

Comment: When space is held, the sounds are continually repeated very fast. I want to be able to delay the rate at which they repeat when space is held.

Comment: For example, play sound x times in a second(time) when space is held?

Comment: Yeah, AudioEnable is being called in update so the sounds right now just play too fast

Comment: Ok. What are you even doing.Maybe there is a better and simple way of solving this problem.

Comment: I want to be able to continually fire bullets when spacebar is held and have sound effects to go with it. Because the sounds are playing in update, once per frame sound effects is very annoying and overlap eachother. I would like to delay the sound effects slightly so that they are played constantly while spacebar is held but at a slower rate than update because it doesnt sound good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your comments, you need a cool down timer. A timer that counts. If the timer reaches the set value, you can shoot. When you shoot, you reset the timer. In this case, you can increase or decrease `coolDownTime` since it will control how many bullets are shot.

Also, rename the audio variable to something else. There is a variable with this name from `MonoBehaviour`, in the latest version of Unity and you will get warnings for this.

Finally, cache the `AudioSource`  component in the `Start()` function so that you don't have to do  `GetComponent<AudioSource>();` every time you shoot.

```
public AudioClip[] fireSounds;
AudioSource bulletAudio;

//Every 0.5 seconds(Change this to your needs)
const float coolDownTime = 0.5f;
float startingTime = 0f;

void Start()
{
    bulletAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    startingTime = Time.time;
}

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //Check if we have reached the cool down timer
        if (Time.time > startingTime + coolDownTime)
        {
            //We have. Now reset timer
            startingTime = Time.time;

            playAudio();
        }
    }
}

void playAudio()
{
    bulletAudio.PlayOneShot(fireSounds[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, fireSounds.Length)]);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Shot");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    void AudioEnable()
    {
        if (SoundPLaying)
            return;            

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            SoundPLaying = true;
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Interval = 1000;  //1000 milliseconds. Ajust this time to be equal to length of fire sound.

            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { SoundPLaying = false; timer.Dispose(); };
            timer.Start();

            Invoke("Audio", audioDelay);
        }
    }

    void Audio()
    {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>(); // play fire sounds from array when space is pressed
        audio.PlayOneShot(fireSounds[Random.Range(0, fireSounds.Length)]);
    }
```

Comment: There are few things wrong with this. *1*.You will be creating new `Timer` Object every frame. *2*.You will get an exception from Unity that says something like *"xxx can only be called from the main thread"*